# Iterating through multiple variables while performing a calculation and saving result? List comprehension, enumerate() - Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, enumerate

I have a range of temperatures ('T') (0 - 100 inclusive) and a range of humidities ('RH') (0-1.00 inclusive) so 101 values in each list.

For each step through temp I would like to run a calculation for the range of humidities, so at T=0 I calculate for every RH in the list and save the results of each calculation (returns an np.array), then at T=1 repeat calc for  entire range of RH again and save each result and so on...

I am using list comprehension to iterate over the two lists:

```
ray2 = np.zeros(np.size(T)*np.size(RH))
ray18 = np.zeros(np.size(T)*np.size(RH))

for x,y in [(x,y) for x in T for y in RH]:

    ray2, ray18 = rayleigh(T[x], RH[y], f, del2, del18)
```

I cannot figure out how to incorporate a counter into the list comprehension to save all 10201 results as an array.

Comment: First, why are you creating a list comprehension just to loop over it? Why not a generator expression, or just doing the loop on the for statement directly?

Comment: Meanwhile, a list comprehension gives you a list. You can call `enumerate` on that the same as on any other iterable. So... what problem are you having?

Comment: @abarnert See spencerchads comment on my answer below. He is having a problem with "saving each individual calc into an array. [He] cannot figure out how to put a counter in to iterate through the empty arrays created. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create n by m zeros matrix, then save all the data to it

```
ray2 = np.zeros((np.size(T), np.size(RH)))
ray18 = np.zeros((np.size(T), np.size(RH)))

for idx, t_ele in enumerate(T):
    for idx_rh, rh_ele in enumerate(RH):

        ray2[idx][idx_rh], ray18[idx][idx_rh] = rayleigh(t_ele , rh_ele , f, del2, del18)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want ray2 and ray18 to remain as one-dimensional arrays, then you can address them using the method seen here: [Treating a 1D data structure as 2D grid](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212808/treating-a-1d-data-structure-as-2d-grid).

The code for this follows:

EDIT: After clarification I have adjusted the code.

```py
ray2 = np.zeros(np.size(T)*np.size(RH))
ray18 = np.zeros(np.size(T)*np.size(RH))

for i, t in enumerate(T):
    for j, rh in enumerate(RH):
        index = i*np.size(RH) + j
        ray2[index], ray18[index] = rayleigh(t, rh, f, del2, del18)
```

However, if you are okay with using matrices, then you should probably use the solution posted by @galaxyan.

Comment: Sure I can use a nested loop instead of list comprehension to achieve the same thing. **But what I am having issues with is saving each individual calc into an array**. I cannot figure out how to put a counter in to iterate through the empty arrays created.

Comment: @spencerchad, Ahh sorry. Thanks for the clarification, I've adjusted my answer. If you want ray2 and ray18 to remain as one dimensional arrays then you should be able to use the code I have posted (might need some syntax fixes), otherwise if you are happy to use matrices, follow the answer posted by galaxyan.